# grails spring security redirect after fail to Authorize

Tags: spring, security, grails

I have a request where if the user fails to authorize in a method call we need to redirect him to a specific page

Use case
The user can register at the system just with name and email, but later when he tries to perform some actions, he is required to fill the entire profile.

We will protect the method with a HAS_FULL_PROFILE role

It's based on authorization, not authentication

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what the question is, but it sounds like you want to control things using the URL-mapping in combination with profiles.

Try [this](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html#5.2%20Simple%20Map%20in%20Config.groovy) link. Setting up your URL-mappings so that only users with the HAS_FULL_PROFILE can reach some areas until they "upgrade" their profile to this one.